# Multiple commands by one click

Tags: rhino3d, rhinoceros

How can I run multiple commands using one shortcut?

I'm gonna run `dupfaceborder, offsetcrvonsrf, split, extrudesrf` by specified distances like 50 times, is it possible to convert them into one command?
I read about it and know it's possible using python, but I'm not able to do that so I need another easier way.

Comment: In this link macro basics are explained:
https://wiki.mcneel.com/rhino/basicmacros?s[]=macro&s[]=basic
This is a part of it:
You can create macros...
The tools you need
 Your brain :P
 The Rhino Help file - lists all Rhino commands and their sub-options. This is your most important reference. Pressing F1 (Windows) or the :?: toolbar button (Mac) will get you to the online help.
    The Rhino MacroEditor, a built-in interface for creating and testing your macros.
    An understanding of how to add your macros to your workflow in the form of aliases or toolbar buttons (explained here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for macros. You can chain commands together and then attach to buttons. Check out the docs here:
https://wiki.mcneel.com/rhino/macroscriptsetup

Comment: Please consider adding at least a part of the answer from the link to your answer here since link only answers will become invalid if the target url changes over time. Right now what you have provided is more of a comment than an answer.